# Case in where single-row subquery returns more than one row

Tags: sql, oracle

My table test99 return:

```
empno
------
7698
7900
```

When I call this query, I get ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row.

```
Select * from emp
  where empno in
   (case 
      when 1 > 0 then (Select empno from test99 )
   else 9999
   end)
```

Other solution:

```
 Select * from emp
  where empno in
   (case 
      when 1 = :MY_PARAMETER then (Select empno from test99 )
      when 1 < :MY_PARAMETER then (Select empno from test88 )
      when 1 > :MY_PARAMETER then (Select empno from test77 )
   else 9999
   end)
```

Comment: The issue is with the case block. In the when clause multiple records are being records are being returned, but the query is expecting only a single record. That is the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, it is a good idea to avoid `case` expressions in the `where` clause.  In this case, you can easily rewrite this as:

```
Select *
from emp
where 1 > 0 and empno in (Select empno from test99 ) or
      1 <= 0 and empno = 9999;
```

I am guessing that `empno` is never `9999`, so this would be more simply as:

```
Select *
from emp
where 1 > 0 and empno in (Select empno from test99 );
```

However, you may want the logic:  If `1 > 0` then test for inclusion in `test99`, otherwise choose *all* employees. For that:

```
Select *
from emp
where 1 <= 0 or empno in (Select empno from test99 );
```

EDIT:

For your expanded condition, you still don't need `case` expressions:

```
where (1 = :MY_PARAMETER and empno in (Select empno from test99 )) or
      (1 < :MY_PARAMETER and empno in (Select empno from test88 )) or
      (1 > :MY_PARAMETER and empno in (Select empno from test77 ))
```

Comment: Tnx for help, but I is it possible in my example use more case sattment? I'm Updated question.